# What's the best way to search for a string in a file?

Tags: ruby

The title speaks for itself really. I only want to know if it exists, not where it is. Is there a one liner to achieve this?

Comment: sorry, I like your question, but, please, rename it. I was catched in `detect` function speciality (return first element, not all, uh)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
File.open(filename).grep(/string/)
```

This loads the whole file into memory (slurps the file). You should avoid file slurping [when dealing with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-not-a-good-practice). That means loading one line at a time, instead of the whole file.

```
File.foreach(filename).grep(/string/)
```

It's good practice to clean up after yourself rather than letting the garbage collector handle it at some point. This is more important if your program is long-lived and not just some quick script. Using a code block ensures that the `File` object is closed when the block terminates.

```
File.foreach(filename) do |file|
  file.grep(/string/)
end
```

Comment: This actually leaks a file descriptor which could cause a serious problem. Here's a cleaner alternative that will close the file after it's used. `open('some.txt') { |f| f.grep(/string/) }`

Comment: And also leads to load the whole file in memory. `open("some.txt") { |f| f.each_line.detect { |line| /re/.match(line) } }`

Comment: -1 because for some reason it returns false when it should be true. Investigating why.

Comment: Guys, I see no reason why File#grep would drag file into memory. Can you show me smth about that in docs?

Comment: I would give priority to multi-line queries over worrying about running out of memory when loading a file for parsing. If you're parsing large files on small/embedded systems, you've got a whole host of optimization concerns that fall outside typical parsing requirements.  I would assume what you're parsing for is fine per-line is if I had intrinsic information to confirm it, but only then.

Comment: This code of yours does not leak file descriptors: `File.foreach(filename).grep(/string/)`.  The file gets opened and closed within the call to `grep`.  If you don't believe it, try printing some messages immediately before and after `grep` and use `strace ./your_program.rb` to see what happens between those two prints.

Comment: I have not found specifications for a File.grep or String.grep method.  What version of ruby is this?

Comment: @JulienLamarche `IO::foreach` and `Enumerable#grep`
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep

Comment: Isn't "slurping" actually the complete opposite? Meaning, reading the entire file in memory.

Comment: What if I don't have line breaks in my big file?

Answer (score 10):

grep for foo OR bar OR baz, stolen from [ruby1line.txt](http://www.fepus.net/ruby1line.txt).

```
$  ruby -pe 'next unless $_ =~ /(foo|bar|baz)/' < file.txt
```

Comment: Link seems broken, is this a mirror? http://www.das-labor.org/svn/ruby/sandbox/oneliner.txt

Comment: Ruby oneliner  http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/ruby/ruby-one-liners.html#h5 @dimitris mistriotis

Answer (score 7):

If your OS has a grep package, you could use a system call:

```
system("grep meow cat_sounds.txt")
```

This will return true if `grep` returns anything, false if it does not.

If you find yourself on a system with `grep`, you may find this is the "best" way because Ruby can be slow when it comes to file operations.

Comment: he hasnt specified his os yet =\

Comment: I think it's best to assume he's sane.

Comment: Funily enough it was a rakefile I was creating when I came up with this question, so I can even re-factor this to sh "grep meow cat_sounds.txt" :-)

Comment: And it still returns true / false? Cool! http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/FileUtils.html#M000018 haha! The example is even grepping!

Comment: What does sanity have to do with the fact that not all OSes have a "grep" command?

Comment: I find it insane that people try to run Ruby on Windows, given all the pitfalls.

Comment: Ruby works on Windows quite well actually. But then you have the gems....*grimace of pain*. Still, it's my language of choice for system scripts.

Comment: Do people actually use Windows in production? I think that's insane. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well it seems eed3si9n has the one liner down, here's the longer solution:

```
f = File.new("file.txt")
text = f.read
if text =~ /string/ then
#relevant code
end
```

Comment: You need to quote your file name.

Comment: yeah just noticed while you posted this

Comment: This reads in entire file and is not as efficient as other line-oriented commands in this post

Answer (score 1):

This reads the file only to the first appearance of 'string'
and processes it line by line - not reading the whole file at once.

```
def file_contains_regexp?(filename,regexp)
  File.foreach(filename) do |line|
    return true if line =~ regexp
  end
  return false
end
```