# How to scan text file for string, and run code if string isn't there?

Tags: ruby, text

I have tried:

```rb
elsif file.grep(/Mode: 1/)
   puts "test"
else
   puts "test but else"
```

Codacy is saying this is wrong. Is there a way to improve this? According to Codacy:

```rb
unexpected token kELSIF (Using Ruby 2.2 parser; configure using `TargetRubyVersion` parameter, under `AllCops`)

unexpected token kELSE (Using Ruby 2.2 parser; configure using `TargetRubyVersion` parameter, under `AllCops`)
```

Comment: it should start with `if`, not `elsif`

Comment: And it should end with `end`.

Comment: And `grep` is `Enumerable` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to search for a string in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633396/whats-the-best-way-to-search-for-a-string-in-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IO::read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/IO.html#method-c-read) to assign text file content and then [`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-include-3F) for checking.

```
file_string = File.read('path/to/file')

if file_string.include?('substring')
  puts 'Yes'
else
  puts 'No'
end
```

Also you can replace it by [`String#match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) (it is faster).

`file_string.match?(/pattern/)` will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you so much! you're a true lifesaver. I'm new to ruby, and this helps loads. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: if I want to print something from file it shows blank output even though condition is true as the text matches
 File.open("fahad.txt","r") do |i|
if i.read().include?("major")
     puts i.read()

  end
end